# NSZombieEnabled without debugger

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, nszombie, nszombieenabled

We have a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash in our iOS application but it happens only when certain external accessory is connected. Unfortunately this accessory doesn't allow debugging (no pass-through connection). Is it possible to permanently enable `NSZombieEnabled` for the application so it's active even when the application is started directly on the device?

Comment: What if you just don't use the debugger, but still run from XCode with zombies enabled?  You can turn the debugger off in the "Edit Scheme..." area.

Comment: If I run it from XCode it doesn't happen. It never happens on the simulator and never happens on the device if the accessory is disconnected.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean (thought the device was connected wirelessly)...in that case try using the C code `setenv("NSZombieEnabled", "YES", 1);` as the first line in your `main` function (in main.m).

Comment: It doesn't work. Probably these things are initialized even before main() gets called.

Answer (score 1):

The `NSZombieEnabled` environment variable is used to set a corresponding `NSZombieEnabled` global variable, declared in `Foundation/NSDebug.h`.

The environment variable is read very early, before `main()`, but you can set the `NSZombieEnabled` global to `YES` in your `main()` function before calling `UIApplicationMain()` (or `NSApplicationMain()`).